# Required Facebook Extended Permissions : Graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I'm sorry if this is a re-post but no matter what search terms I use I can't find what I am looking for.

First, I'm developing in PHP, but the graph api just uses url calls so that shouldn't matter. I would like to avoid using the REST api.

I have an application that requires publish_stream and offline_access. The app is pointless for a user to install if they deny these permissions. How do I make them required?

I know I can check to make sure if the user has the permissions later, but that is a hassle and I'm trying to avoid it. But if this isn't possible that is what I'll have to do.

Comment: Bottom line: you **can't** force a user to accept these permissions.

Comment: Okay, that's all I needed to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the REST API to authenticate, but you do need to check if the use has authenticated or not.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/

You can use the javascript SDK instead of the REST API to prompt for authentication. You can use javascript for almost everything, not URL redirects needed.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

There was actually a recent Facebook blog post about how to check for permissions, which is also helpful.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/576/

If the user isn't authenticated, then place them on a page that has a button to prompt for authorization. Once granted, then you can redirect to the real page.

Comment: I have authentication working in the Graph API just fine, I just didn't want to have to check if they gave me permissions every time I want to use them. Oh well I guess it's not that bad.

Comment: You can cache the permission information, like in a session variable. The auth token comes with an expiration date/time, so you know how long it is good for. Then you don't have to check every time.

Comment: Yeah, I don't need to do that because I don't need to check permissions during a user's session. This is because I want to run a batch operation on all of my users. This is good advice though, I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: If you want to run a batch on multiple users, then you want to have your app login and get it's own auth token. Scroll down until you find the App Login section on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/